# What does the colon mean in struct declarations in C?

Tags: c++, c

Reading the code of TeXmacs, I saw this:

```
struct texmacs_input_rep : concrete_struct {
...
};
```

What does that mean?

This syntax is defined in the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), p113, but I didn't find the meaning of it, but that's because I don't know how to read grammar rules.

Because `concrete_struct` is another `struct`, that contains functions looking like a constructor and a virtual destructor, and because I read elsewhere that classes in C++ are actually `struct` with public members by default, I guess that this is the way of doing inheritance with `struct` in C (because it is the C standard...).

Is this correct?

Comment: If this is only regarding a C issue you should remove the c++ tag. In c++ that declaration is right.

Comment: That syntax is not defined in the C standard... Are you sure you know how to read the grammar rules?

Comment: Right, I read too fast, and I was sceptical it was C too... And yes I know how to read grammar rules.

Comment: And I always attributed struct to being C, I didn't know it has been extended in C++. That's why I deliberately tagged it both C and C++.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is C++ syntax and equivalent to this:

```
class texmacs_input_rep : public concrete_struct {
public:
...
};
```

This is the normal syntax for inheritance of classes, here `texmacs_input_rep` is inherited from `concrete_struct`.

#### About that syntax in C:

The C-Standard you linked to defines (6.7.2.1):

```
struct-or-union-speciﬁer:
    struct-or-union identiﬁeropt { struct-declaration-list }
    struct-or-union identiﬁer

struct-or-union:
    struct
    union
```

So according to C it must be `struct`, followed by an optional identifer, followed by `{`. Or only `struct` followed by an identifer (a forward declaration). In neither case there is room for an additional `: ...` in there.

The `:` mentioned later in that paragraph of the standard is about bit-field widths, like this;

```
struct foo {
  unsigned a : 4;
  unsigned b : 3;
};
```

Here `a` and `b` are only 4 and 3 bits wide, but that's different syntax than in the question.

Answer (score 7):

GCC doesn't like it (in C mode of course).

And looking at the spec, I don't see that defined at page 113 (6.7.2.1), it says :

```
struct-declarator:
    declarator
    declarator_opt : constant-expression
```

which is the syntax for bitfields like this :

```
struct blah {
    int a : 4;
    int b : 4;
};
```

So in summary: this is not C, it's C++ and it's inheritance like class inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure this is C?

The standard document you linked to does not describe such a syntax, that I could see.

This looks like C++, where it indeed is used to say that the struct inherits another struct. The [TeXmacs compilation page](http://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/download/sources.en.html) recommends you to use a C++ compiler, which (to me) implies that it's written in C++, not C.

I took a quick look in the TeXmacs source archive, and saw lots of ".cpp" files.

Comment: Have you not looked at the C spec that the poster references, he is quite correct.... I'm also baffled by what the spec is trying to say though.

Comment: @Benj: I sure looked, and I don't agree, he is not correct. See 246tNt's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `:` in the text of the Standard is not part of the C construction. It is there to separate the thing being defined and its definition.

There is no valid use of the `:` in a struct declaration.